# Does disk encryption or key ring store anything in hardware?

Tags: encryption, luks, gnome-keyring, tpm

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 (soon 22.04), and am wondering if Ubuntu by default stores any key material in a hardware store like TPM. Specifically I am using standard LUKS disk encryption during setup, and the keyring is used by Chrome to store passwords.

What I want to do is buy a new SSD, switch it out and do a clean re-install. But I would like to be able to put back in my old SSD and boot the old system. Is this possible? I am now worried I might lock myself out by resetting some TPM store or something.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 will use TPM it was recently blogged about (https://ubuntu.com/blog/tpm-backed-full-disk-encryption-is-coming-to-ubuntu) so I don't like the changes of 20.04 having it :)  The encryption is set by what release the system was installed with; 17.10 for example had different encryption to 20.04 for example for some installs (ie. *encrypted home partition only was allowed for in 17.10*), but I can't see encryption being a problem (*my opinion only*)